Putting email of authors in springer nature template together after address
I am stuck with a very basic question. How should I put email ids of the authors in the the springer nature template. My knowledge of latex is very basic. Thank you for great help.
\begin{document}
%
\title{Paper Title}
%
%\titlerunning{Abbreviated paper title}
% If the paper title is too long for the running head, you can set
% an abbreviated paper title here
%
\author{authors1\and
authors2\and
authors3\and
authors4\and
authors5\and
authors6\and
authors7}
%
\authorrunning{authors1 et al.}
% First names are abbreviated in the running head.
% If there are more than two authors, 'et al.' is used.
%
\institute{University name, Address}
%
\maketitle              % typeset the header of the contribution
%
\begin{abstract}

Edit1
Below is the complete minimal example:
% This is samplepaper.tex, a sample chapter demonstrating the
% LLNCS macro package for Springer Computer Science proceedings;
% Version 2.21 of 2022/01/12
%
\documentclass[runningheads, orivec]{llncs}
%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% T1 fonts will be used to generate the final print and online PDFs,
% so please use T1 fonts in your manuscript whenever possible.
% Other font encondings may result in incorrect characters.
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
% Used for displaying a sample figure. If possible, figure files should
% be included in EPS format.
%
% If you use the hyperref package, please uncomment the following two lines
% to display URLs in blue roman font according to Springer's eBook style:
%\usepackage{color}
%\renewcommand\UrlFont{\color{blue}\rmfamily}
%\urlstyle{rm}
%
\begin{document}
%
\title{Paper Title}
%
%\titlerunning{Abbreviated paper title}
% If the paper title is too long for the running head, you can set
% an abbreviated paper title here
%
\author{authors1\and
authors2\and
authors3\and
authors4\and
authors5\and
authors6\and
authors7}
%
\authorrunning{authors1 et al.}
% First names are abbreviated in the running head.
% If there are more than two authors, 'et al.' is used.
%
\institute{University name, Address}
%
\maketitle              % typeset the header of the contribution
%
\begin{abstract}
The abstract should briefly summarize the contents of the paper in
150--250 words.

\keywords{First keyword  \and Second keyword \and Another keyword.}
\end{abstract}
%
%
%
\section{First Section}

\end{document}

After compiling, it should like as below:


Can you define what you mean by "email ids"?

Thank you for the response @Werner. By email Id I mean, emails of each author like manu@univeristyname.edu. All the authors have the same university name.

The title of your query is a bit confusing: The name of the llncs document class is short for "lecture notes in computer science". It is not the "Springer nature" document class, which is named sn-jnl. Please clarify.

Thank you for informing me. I might be using the wrong template all together. The link provided to me for downloading the latex template for the conference is: https://www.springer.com/gp/computer-science/lncs/conference-proceedings-guidelines LaTeX2e Proceedings Templates download

The email id problem I have now resolved by using the syntax: \institute{University name, Address\\\email{\{author1, author2\}@university.edu}}

No. Please just adjust the posting so that the name document class you actually use is reflected in the title of your posting. I am in no position to judge which document class you ought to be using.

Sorry, I compiled and checked it. The template needs llncs.cls file.
